# C - What does 'typedef struct SymTable *SymTable_T; mean?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, abstract-data-type

I'm working on making a symtable ADT and I am absolutely rubbish with pointers. Can someone break down the statement `typedef struct SymTable *SymTable_T;` for me? What is `typedef` doing? What is `*SymTable_T` pointing to?

Additionally for bonus internet points, could someone point me in the right direction if I need my SymTable to make copies of `<key, value>` pairs? My guess was this:

```
typedef struct SymTable *SymTable_T;
{
    char *key;
    int *value;
    struct SymTable *next; //I will have linked lists to avoid collisions
};
```

Comment: You should not `typedef` a pointer. That hides its semantics and will likely lead to confusion.

Answer (score 3):

`typedef struct SymTable *SymTable_T;` would be much easier to understand if it had been expressed as follows:

`typedef struct SymTable* SymTable_T;`

So, this is declaring `SymTable_T` to be a pointer to a `struct SymTable`.

The stuff following that declaration is rubbish, and I do not even think it should compile.  Perhaps the following was meant:

```
struct SymTable
{
    char* key;
    int* value;
    struct SymTable* next; //I will have linked lists to avoid collisions
};

typedef struct SymTable* SymTable_T;
```

Comment: I have a header file I am supposed to be using (this is homework) and it has the prototype `typedef struct SymTable *SymTable_T`. Is it incorrect? Wouldn't the `*SymTable_T` be a pointer to `struct SymTable` in its original syntax?

Comment: I said it would be "much easier to understand".  This means that both syntaxes are valid, and they both mean the exact same thing.  It just happens that your professor's syntax perference is, in my humble opinion, outdated, counter-intuitive, and unsuitable for teaching.

Answer (score 1):

A `typedef` statement defines a pointer-to-a-struct type as a new type.

After `typedef struct SymTable *SymTable_T;`

Wherever you do a variable declaration:

```
SymTable_T newTable;
```

Will be equal with doing:

```
struct SymTable *newTable;
```

On your code at the end, you probably are attempting to define the type as described but also declare the struct type at the same type.

This is not done right - in fact, in that way you have it, is like just having a code block with nothing more than variable declarations after your `typedef` statement, which is valid but does nothing close to what you want.

Try specifying your type:

```
struct SymTable
{
    char *key;
    int *value;
    struct SymTable *next; //I will have linked lists to avoid collisions
};
```

And then using typedef to do what described above.